# android chrome html5 live audio stops playing after 5min

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, html5-audio, icecast

I have an icecast live stream that plays in a webpage using the html5 audio element.

On android phones using chrome the live stream stops playing after about 5-10 minutes in for no apparent reason. Using firefox on android it plays indefinitely with no issues.

I'm not sure how to even approach troubleshooting this. How can I find out what's happening and find a solution (besides telling the user to use a different browser...)

My code is very simple:

```
<p>The stream may take up to 30 seconds to load.</p>
<audio controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/stream.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

The issue happens on every android phone I've tried and persists despite enabling 'stay awake' in developer options and keeping chrome open with the screen on.

Comment: Do you have any problems on Chrome on a desktop? Im experiencing the same problem but on a computer. Could really use the help

Comment: For me it works fine on desktop, but I'm making progress on a workaround. The first thing I tried (that may work for you) was to use muses radio player (muses.org) which seems to detect audio stalls and reconnect. I don't like how muses interface is designed so I'm working on a similar solution in JavaScript. I'll post an answer if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this behavior was caused by a bug in the then-current version of chrome for android. An update to chrome browser fixed the issue.